# Error: Fail to resolve : com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

I want to add the carousel view in my first android app but I am getting this error.

When I add a dependency to the support library in the `build.gradle` like this:

[image]

After installing repository and SDK , it again shows error.

How can I add repository without upgrading Android Studio. I am using Android studio 1.5.1

Is there any other method for sliding pictures like carouselview?

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Restart`

Comment: Why aren't you using the newest Android Studio (2.1.3)?

Comment: it didn't work in my last android version so i am now reinstalling it again.

Comment: it worked on Android Studio 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

That's because you may have installed the incorrect support repository. To do this, open your **SDK manager** and install the correct one.

[image]

Also, try re-building the gradle & restarting the Android Studio!